# Is a Spring Boot microservice with a non-Java front-end client possible?

Tags: javascript, java, client, load-balancing, microservices

I've implemented the shell of a microservices-based REST API application. I have simply followed the guides on Pivotal Springs' own documentation using Eureka and Ribbon for load balancing. Everything works. I have a discovery server with a handful of independent services which can register with the discovery server.

Now, my problem is that I might prefer not to write my client-side app in Java - maybe Angular or node.js, etc. However, the load balancing and connecting to the discovery server is all done in Java in the examples I've followed.

Is it possible to use JavaScript to do the same things that the Eureka client does with the Spring Boot microservices so that I don't need to be constrained in my choices of browser client technology? Does anybody have any advice for how this should be approached? I had difficulty finding any articles that cover this, to be honest.

Comment: Don't ask about libraries if you don't want your question to be closed. :)

Comment: Oh ok, I didnt realise that, thanks. I'll amend the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you should not be doing load balancing/service discover etc. in the front-end. So the question about whether it is possible in JavaScript or with which libraries is irrelevant.

Typically you'll have an API gateway or a (load balancing) proxy which works with your service registry and routes requests accordingly. In the current project we use Consul for service registry and Nginx + consul-template as proxy. We plan to migrate to some API gateway.

With this setup your front-end will connect to just one central endpoint which would do load balancing/routing to individual service instances behind the scenes. Thus your front-end will not need to implement anything like Eureka/Ribbon etc.

Comment: Ok great. Thanks. This is making more sence now. In the example in a blong in the spring site, they are doing the loadbalncing act within the actual client app, which actually felt wrong. So just out of interest, before I go and write an api gateway from scratch, is there anything available that will do this automatically? Ie I give it a list of ll the endpoints from all my services and it generates an interface layer? I only ask because it seems like some quite boilerplate level stuff and could be available like this.

Comment: Yes, "API gateway" is more-or-less standard software these days but I can't recommend anything. You should not write API gateway, for sure.

Comment: Ok thanks. You have been a great help, and so has @Bharat. I'm going to accept your answer as the solution as it more directly addresses my concearn that loadbalancing in the client felt...weird.

Comment: @gezinspace Load balancing on the client isn't actually wrong either. API gateway adds some overhead you may spare otherwise.

Comment: Ah ok, Ill bear that in mind. Well I suppose that if I use an api gateway it solves my problem of having to decide how to perform loadbalancing and service discovery and makes my life MUCH easier if I decide to switch client technologies as I'll still just be sending http requests to one place, and the server can worry about where the request should go.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Definitely you can choose technology of your choice for developing front end application. From your front end application, you make calls to API endpoint that you expose via your spring boot application.

You might want to expose your services via single API gateway that will help you route requests to designated micro services using your discovery server.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that actually helps. I had some trouble getting my head around the idea that (following the example I had seen in https://spring.io/blog/2015/07/14/microservices-with-spring) all requests wouldnt be routed though one place without knowing about this discovery server. So essentially you are talking about another microservice which is  like a public interface, right? This does the load balancing parts and connects to  the discovery sevice so that the user/client doesnt have to even know about it? Am I on the right lines?

Comment: Yes. Netflix has nice libraries to achieve service discovery (Eureka), load balancing(Ribbon). It is a better practice to expose a single API whose URL is known to the client, and you leave that service to determine which service has to perform the action for a specific request.